# How does polymorphism differ from generics in Java ArrayLists?

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

If I have an `ArrayList<Shape>`, I'm under the impression that within that list I can store objects of class `Shape` or objects that are subclasses of `Shape`.

I've also seen a lot of notation around with things like `ArrayList<T>` or `ArrayList<?>`. Are these the same things? A `T` superclass and all its subclasses can be stored, and the `?` is just a placeholder?

Basically, how does something like `ArrayList<CLASSNAME>` differ from `ArrayList<T>` where you just have the one letter.

Comment: That is a little unclear.

Comment: I'd vote to close, but you probably wouldn't notice.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll try to clarify, one second. EDIT: Clarified.

Comment: T can be anything, ClASSNAME is only one type (and its subs).

Comment: It would depend where you saw the notation, as far as I know, `<T>` is only used in the declaring statement of a generic class, not in the statement that instantiates an object of that type, where you have to use `<CLASSNAME>`

Comment: @arynaq That's assuming there is actually a class(or interface) named `CLASSNAME`. If there isn't, then there is not difference between `ArrayList<CLASSNAME>`, `ArrayList<T>`, and `ArrayList<WarAndPeace_ANovelByLeoTolstoy>` - they are all just binding the template argument to a differently named symbol.

Comment: Note that generics are a form of polymorphism. Polymorphism basically means "something can act in different ways." So, a `List<T>` is polymorphic in that it can be a list of Foos or a list of Bars. A lot of people in Java confuse polymorphism with subclassing, which is another form of polymorphism. This is a bit like confusing "a vehicle" with "a van."

Answer (score 1):

First, the difference is not whether it is one letter as you might think. It is whether `T` is the name of a generic argument or not. If you declare a method like:

```
public <T> void method()
```

as opposed to:

```
public void method()
```

or a class like:

```
public class Whatever<T>
```

as opposed to:

```
public class Whatever
```

then `T` is a generic argument. You then get to use `T` anywhere you want as if it were a real class name, and a real class name will be substituted for `T` at compile time. But this is not the best picture of it, so let's say that the type of `T` is whatever type was passed to the arguments of type T. So, at any given moment, `T` has a value that is a real class name.

So, the difference between `ArrayList<T>` and `ArrayList<Shape>` is that `ArrayList<T>` holds objects of type `T`, whereas `ArrayList<Shape>` holds objects of type `Shape`. The trick is that `T` is whatever type was passed to arguments of type `T`, so it can vary.

Disclaimer: The type `T` does not actually change over time. In most cases, the compiler replaces it with `Object`. However, the compiler is good at hiding that, and it is a good idea to think of `T` changing.

Comment: This is the best answer so far.  Not least because it mentions that the fact that T is a single letter is unimportant.  Using a single letter (T or E or whatever) for a type parameter is just a common convention - it's not required by the language.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ArrayList can't reference any subclass of Shape like this:

```
ArrayList<Shape> blah = new ArrayList<Square>
```

But you can do it this way:

```
ArrayList<? extends Shape> blah = new ArrayList<Square>
```

Polymorphism doesn't work with type parameter. It only works with objects such as:

```
Collection<String> blah = new ArrayList<String>
```

But you have to understand the purpose of using T. T is used to declare a type parameter for class and methods.

Such that when you declare a class with parameter T:

```
 public class ArrayList <T>
```

T acts as a placeholder when the class is instantiated as object.

So in this case:

```
 ArrayList<String>
```

you are replacing T with String in the ArrayList class.

Btw, you aren't suppose to use T as a type for argument. Because T isn't really defined, it is only a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You express `ArrayList<T>` when you're declaring the type / class and `ArrayList<String>` when  you're creating an instance of ArrayList and associate it with the type parameter String.

For example:

```
// class declaration
public class ArrayList<T> extends ... implements ... {
  ...

// Creating an arraylist of string
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>
```

You can think of generics as a type variable. Hence instead of creating a class which only works with String:

```
public class MyArray {

  String get(int index) { ... }

}
```

You can create an array class that works with any arbitrary type

```
public class MyArray<T> {

  T get(int index) { .. }

}
```